# Error during making of android source file

Tags: android-source

When i am building android source code i am getting following error:

```
external/webkit/Source/WebCore/xml/XPathParser.cpp: In member function 'WebCore::XPath::Expression* WebCore::XPath::Parser::parseStatement(const WTF::String&, WTF::PassRefPtr<WebCore::XPathNSResolver>, WebCore::ExceptionCode&)':
external/webkit/Source/WebCore/xml/XPathParser.cpp:480:39: error: too many arguments to function 'int WebCore::XPath::xpathyyparse()'
In file included from external/webkit/Source/WebCore/xml/XPathParser.cpp:51:0:
out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libwebcore_intermediates/Source/WebCore/XPathGrammar.hpp:106:5: note: declared here
make: *** [out/target/product/generic/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libwebcore_intermediates/Source/WebCore/xml/XPathParser.o] Error 1
```

Can anybody tell me what are the possible errors and solution for that?

Comment: If you build master brunch of AOSP it's possible that it contains some errors. Also maybe you've changed something in the sources and now it is not built. We need more information to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for your input... i freshly downloaded the code from android repository. I didn't make any changes.

Comment: I think that the problem is that you've working on master brunch which is not stable. Try to sync once again in several working days and see if the problem still exists.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you tell me how i can build specific release from the master file.

Comment: For instance, the latest stable release, AFAIK, is 4.2.2_r1. So you need to run the following commands `repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-4.2.2_r1`, then `repo sync` and after that build as you have built before.

Comment: Thanks.. But with the android-4.2.2_r1 release also it is giving same error.Build environment: **OS:Mac OS X v 10.8.2 Xcode: 4.5.2.** Please let me know if anything more is required.

Comment: I tried building the source code by commenting the **xpathyyparse()** function call and its sucessful. Can anybody suggest me that will it affect?

Comment: Try to search the invokation of this method in Android sources using cgrep command.

Answer (score 0):

Check your bison's version, if it's 2.6 or higher, there would be a bug of webkit, see [Bug 92264](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=92264).

Somebody discuss the same question: [libwebcore build error on Mac 10.8](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-building/T1Myr6Sz3ms/7nlX2OCqZygJ), you can learn about how to solve it.